# What are the upsides to using an ExcelWriter when exporting DataFrames with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export

I am using pandas dataframes to store some data and I want to export it into an excel file for easier reading/formatting.

I tried just running

```
df.to_excel('sheet.xlsx')
```

and it saves the sheet.xlsx with no problems in my working folder. I want to know why I would want to use an ExcelWriter object before using the .to_excel() method?

It seems like there are many extra unnecessary steps like creating the object and then saving the object again.

Comment: Appending to existing sheets, mainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a simple data dump to excel for a single dataframe, then the `to_excel` method works just fine. The `ExcelWriter` object is there for situations where you're looking for greater control over the output excel file. With `ExcelWriter` you can for example:

- [Write an excel file with multiple worksheets](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html) (as already noted by Coldspeed).
- [Write multiple dataframes to the same worksheet.](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#handling-multiple-pandas-dataframes)
- [Apply advanced formatting](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#adding-conditional-formatting-to-dataframe-output). The `to_excel` method does offer some excel formatting options (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Export-to-Excel)), but when using an `ExcelWriter` object you have much more options.
- [Add charts to the excel file.](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#adding-charts-to-dataframe-output)